# Why is this keyboard shortcut (⌃⌥L) triggering the following text input...?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

In the past, I've used the ⌃⌥L key combination as a keyboard shortcut without any issues.

However, a couple months back, this changed.  Now, when I press ⌃⌥L, e.g. with a text editor open, the first time I press it, " L1 " is automatically typed.  The second time I press it, " L2 " is automatically typed.  The third time I press it, " L3 " is automatically typed.  The fourth time I press it, " L4 " is automatically typed.  The fifth time I press it, the cycle described here begins anew, i.e. " L1 " is automatically typed, and so on.

I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing this weird behavior.  Any suggestions on how to get to the root of this?  Thanks!

Comment: Is this in all apps, or just something that could be described as 'a terminal' ?

Comment: This happens in all apps, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Then I'd guess it has to be some 3rd party app. I don't know of anything built-in that could do that.

Comment: have you tried [the CheatSheet App](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/04/18/how-to-view-mac-apps-keyboard-shortcuts/) to find out sth more ?

Comment: Have you checked system preferences-> keyboard -> shortcuts for any configurations you may have made and forgot about?

Comment: @1NN I'm not clear on how the CheatSheet App would be helpful here.  Can you explain?

Comment: @Joe I checked my system preferences keyboard shortcuts, and this shortcut does not appear there at all.

Comment: Isn't there some way to read my system logs and simply see what app is being triggered when I press this key combination?

Comment: What OS and window manager?

Comment: CheatSheet App: Seeing in which applications the shortcut is active may give you a hint from where it comes from.

Comment: @Barmar MacOS Monterey 12.0.1

Comment: @1NN Got it.  Does CheatSheetApp allow you to search for keyboard shortcuts across all of your installed apps?